# MFSideMenuContainerViewController not working in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone

in my application i am integrating like facebook slider by using MFSideMenuContainerViewController in storyboard.but only black screen i got when application start.
Here is my code for app did finish loading

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];


    HomeContainerVC *container = (HomeContainerVC *)self.window.rootViewController;



    navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeNav"];
    HomeSideMenuVC *homeSideMenu = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homesidemenu"];
    [container setLeftMenuViewController:homeSideMenu];
    [container setCenterViewController:navController];
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue on phone running iOS 8.0.1. Seems to work fine on 8.1.
What SDK were/are you seeing this issue with?